# VBA Subroutine declaration issue stoping excel VBA from properly executing

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I am working on a simple subroutine to pull values from the Primary Worksheet and to move those values to the additional sheets. When I run the VBA macro it never gets past the subroutine declaration, any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro2()
Dim rCell As Range, ws As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Sheets.Add().Name = "Temp"
.Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,         CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("B1"), Unique:=True
For Each rCell In Sheets("Temp").Range("D2", Sheets("Temp").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsEmpty(rCell) Then
        .Range("D2").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=rCell
        If SheetExists(rCell.Text) Then
            Set ws = Sheets(rCell.Text)
        Else
            Set ws = Worksheet.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count - 1))
            ws.Name = rCell
        End If
        With .AutoFilter.Range
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End With
    End If
Next rCell
Sheets("Temp").Delete
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

added Function

```
 Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
 Dim sht As Worksheet

 If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 On Error Resume Next
 Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
 On Error GoTo 0
 SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
 End Function
```

New error

```
extract range has a illegal or missing field name
```

@

```
.Range("D2", .Range("D"&Rows.Count).End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter  Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("B1"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: You've declared ws as worksheets, it should be worksheet. Worksheets is a collection of worksheet, so can't have a name method/property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>When I run that code, it says:</strike>

> Compile Error:
>
> Sub or Function not defined

and then highlights the `SheetExists` function.  Either `SheetExist` is a function you forgot to include in your form, or it's a custom function that wasn't included in your example.

**EDIT:** Wow, there's a lot going on here.

If you step through the code after that, you'll also get a Run-time 1004 error ("Application-defined or object-defined error") here:

```
.Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("B1"), Unique:=True
```

Try changing that to:

```
.Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("B1"), Unique:=True
```

From there, change this:

```
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count - 1))
ws.Name = rCell
```

to this:

```
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count - 1)).Name = rCell
```

From there, though, I'm not sure what `With .AutoFilter.Range` is supposed to be doing, unless you meant `With Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range`.

From a debugging standpoint, you really want to add `On Error Goto ErrRoutine` at the beginning of your code, then add this to the end of your routine:

```
    Exit Sub

ErrRoutine:

    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume
```

And put a breakpoint on `MsgBox Err.Description` to step back to the offending line.

Comment: any suggestions why that is happening? 'SheetExist' is included in my form. as far as the other error everything should work .. did I make a typo?

Comment: added a function with this code as a workaround. but new error introduced here is the added code
'Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
 End Function'
 but recieve new error @ ws.Name = rCell for .Name with the error of methode or data member not found.

Comment: Still And error with Methods or data member just now in new line 
' .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy ws.Range' on the ws.Range

Comment: Your declaration is wrong, ws as worksheets should be ws as worksheet

Comment: new error extract range has a illegal or missing field name @     .Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("B1"), Unique:=True

Comment: I mean this as nicely as possible, but did you just copy and paste a bunch of code from a site and create a function around that?  It seems like **none** of your code works, and you get stuck on every error that pops up.  You should take a step back, figure out what you are trying to do, and understand the code you are using.

Comment: No worries I expect to be given constructive criticism. But no I am very new to VBA in excel and IM not doing this for me. I was requested by a Adjunct instructor to do something, but he wasn't very specific so I took what I new about functions in VBA for excel and did the best I could with the info provided.

Comment: The issue seems to me is that I am taking the wrong approach to do what was being asked. My experience is mainly in Perl & php scripting.

Comment: From what I gathered he is asking to take the values in (column D) (Row 2) and move down till it reaches and empty cell, and then place those values in the corresponding sheets within (column D). and then exit

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged to see exactly where it fails.  For example you aren't trying to add a Sheet called Temp when one already exists.  Debug and find exactly where it fails.

I

Comment: k it wont debug as its a compile error saying that my sub is not defined wont go past my subroute declaration